# Reading an Excel sheet which contains an image fails

Tags: phpspreadsheet

Using the following code, I want to open an existing Excel sheet:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Helper\Sample;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
$inputFileName = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$my_file;
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
// ...Here i fill out some cells
// And then save the file with the same name (to overwrite)
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save($inputFileName);
```

But the following fault message is displayed:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Exception: 
File zip:///[...]/output/ciclo_pm_3_71_285_395.xlsx#xl/media/image1.jpeg
does not exist in [...]/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet
/Writer/Xlsx/ContentTypes.php:186 Stack trace: #0 [...]/vendor/phpoffice
/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx/ContentTypes.php(126): 
PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer
\Xlsx\ContentTypes->getImageMimeType('zip:///www/htdo...') #1 /[...]
/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx.php(223):
PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer
\Xlsx\ContentTypes->writeContentTypes(Object(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet
\Spreadsheet), false) #2 [...]/ajax_stueli_einlesen.php(350): 
PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx->save('/www/htdocs/w00...') #3 {main} 
thrown in [...]/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer
/Xlsx/ContentTypes.php on line 186
```

When I remove the image from the Excel sheet, it works.
The fault seems to occur whem (over)writing the file.
Why does PHPSpreadsheet say "file not exists"? The file is part of the Excel-Sheet, so it DOES exists, doesn't it?

I'm helpless... ;-(
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is the image actually an external file rather than an embedded image?

Comment: Hi DFriend,i've actually found out, that the problem was not the reading operation but the (over)writing operation.

Comment: My Solution now is to 1. read the sheet 2.edit the sheet 3.Save the sheet under new name 4.delete the old sheet 5.rename the new created sheet to the former name

Answer (score 0):

I just had very same issue with the latest version of the `PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet` package.

As it turned out and as Daniel suggested, the issue happened, because I was trying to overwrite the template spreadsheet.

As soon as I created a new one, the problem vanished.